# Which data structure to store addresses of objects in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, int, long-integer, memory-address

I am beginner in C++,  I need to know which data structure to store addresses of objects in C++.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear.  You generally use a (smart) pointer to store an address:  `MyObj x; MyObj *p = &x;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer. (and here's some SO padding :)

Answer (score 3):

You would need to use something called a "pointer."

Normal variables, such as

```
int a = 5 ;
double r = 39.9 ;
```

Contain values your program should read and use.

Pointers are variables that don't contain values your program should read and use - instead, pointers contain *the address of* some variable your program will read and use.

For example:

```
int *pA ;
pA = &a ;      // pA is now a POINTER to a
*pA = 4 ;      // variable a now contains 4, not 5!
```

So in the above, a few things are happening.  First, the pointer variable pA is declared using a * in its declaration.

```
int *pA ;
```

Next, we give pA a value.  What value?  Why *the address of a!*

```
pA = &a ;
```

The function of pA is like a **secondary handle** to the variable a.  When you modify what pA points to, **you are actually modifying the variable a now**.

```
*pA = 4 ;
```

The variable pA points to at the moment (which is a) gets changed to 4.

See these [videos](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/104/) for a great visualization.